# Select inactive rows if now active row for same CustomerNo existing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**Following table**

`CustomerNo  | MNR_TYPE | TEAM | STATUS   |
 123         | A        | X    | Active   |
 123         | B        | Y    | Active   |
 123         | B        | Y    | Inactive |
 888         | A        | Q    | Active   |
 999         | A        | Z    | Inactive |
 999         | B        | Y    | Inactive |`

Trying to get only Rows with Status = 'Active'. But if there is a CustomerNo which has no entry with an 'Active' Status then I want to take all entries with Status = 'Inactive'.

**Desired output:**

`CustomerNo  | MNR_TYPE | TEAM | STATUS   |
 123         | A        | X    | Active   |
 123         | B        | Y    | Active   |
 888         | A        | Q    | Active   |
 999         | A        | Z    | Inactive |
 999         | B        | Y    | Inactive |`

I have actually found a solution for this with using a CTE and nesting my view but it takes ages (I cancelled after 45 minutes) to execute such a simple query.

```
WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT CustomerNo, STATUS,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNo ORDER BY STATUS) rwn
        FROM Customers 
        WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY CustomerNo, STATUS
    )  
    SELECT cte.CustomerNo, cte.STATUS, pm.MNR_TYPE, pm.Team 
    FROM cte 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT CustomerNo, Team, MNR_TYPE, STATUS 
         FROM Customers
            GROUP BY CustomerNo, MNR_TYPE, Team, STATUS
            HAVING Team IS NOT NULL) pm
    ON pm.CustomerNo = cte.CustomerNo AND pm.STATUS = cte.STATUS 
    WHERE rwn = 1
```

(Also I afterwards create a view from this and then later use it in my final query to concatenate Teams of all same CustomerNos with an FOR XML PATH Function)

Has anybody a better idea??

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this is better but you can do the stats.

** replace #temp1 with the correct table name **

```
select distinct CustomerNo,Mnr_type,team, 
   (select top 1 s.status  from #temp1 s 
      where s.CustomerNo = t.CustomerNo
            and s.MNR_TYPE = t.MNR_TYPE
            and s.TEAM = t.TEAM
            order by s.status 
    ) [status]                      
  from #temp1 t
```

Result

```
CustomerNo  Mnr_type   team       status
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
123         A          X          Active
123         B          Y          Active
888         A          Q          Active
999         A          Z          Inactive
999         B          Y          Inactive
```

or this one using min

```
select CustomerNo,Mnr_type,team, 
   min(status) [status]                    
  from #temp1 t
group by  CustomerNo,Mnr_type,team
```

Result

```
CustomerNo  Mnr_type   team       status
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
123         A          X          Active
123         B          Y          Active
888         A          Q          Active
999         A          Z          Inactive
999         B          Y          Inactive
```

Comment: Tried this out but I also get Rows with Status = 'Inactive' (Row 3 in the table) even though there is an entry with Status = 'Active' for that CustomerNo.

Comment: hi @Mance, which one did you try? perhaps the 2nd one then.

Comment: Hi @masta :)  Sorry I did not see both queries I will check

Comment: got two queries.. using sub and min... both return the desired results where 'active' take precedence.

Comment: I have to check this tommorrow but it looks good in your output

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **WITH TIES** clause in concert with **Dense_Rank()**

```
Declare @YourTable table (CustomerNo int, MNR_TYPE varchar(10),TEAM varchar(10),STATUS varchar(10))
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 123         ,'A'        ,'X'    ,'Active'),
( 123         ,'B'        ,'Y'    ,'Active'),
( 123         ,'B'        ,'Y'    ,'Inactive'),
( 888         ,'A'        ,'Q'    ,'Active'),
( 999         ,'A'        ,'Z'    ,'Inactive'),
( 999         ,'B'        ,'Y'    ,'Inactive'),
( 999         ,'C'        ,'Y'    ,null)


Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  @YourTable 
 Where Status is not null
 Order By Dense_Rank() over (Partition By CustomerNo Order by Status)
```

Returns

```
CustomerNo  MNR_TYPE    TEAM    STATUS
123         A           X       Active
123         B           Y       Active
888         A           Q       Active
999         A           Z       Inactive
999         B           Y       Inactive
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks, your output looks good so far. But I have to check performance tommorrow and will comment it here, it's getting really late.